# Is this php syntax valid? $class->{'something'}()

Tags: php

I was reading a code example of something, and noticed a syntax that isn't familiar to me.

```
$response = $controller->{'home'}();
```

Is that a valid `php` syntax?

Comment: It's just another way to call an object's method.

Comment: You could easily have tested that yourself by writing 3 lines of code, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
$controller->{'home'}
// same as 
$controller->home 
// used to access a property
```

And

```
$controller->{'home'}()
// same as 
$controller->home()
// used to call a method
```

The main benefit is that, by calling `->{stuff}`, you can access properties with different (or strange) names.

Example:

```
$a = new stdClass();
$a->{'@4'} = 4;

print_r($a);
// stdClass Object
// (
//    [@4] => 4
// )
```

You can't do `$a->@4`, but can do `$a->{'@4'}`

See this, for instance: https://3v4l.org/PaOF1

Comment: Is there any benefit of using the {..}() syntax? is this syntax has a name?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. The cool thing about it is that you can call object's methods based on values stored in variables:

```
$whatToExecute = 'home';

$response = $controller->{$whatToExecute}();
```

Good luck!!

Comment: I pretty sure you can do `$controller->$whatToExecute()` as well. Do you know any other benefit of this syntax?

Comment: It comes down to personal preference. Using the curly brackets looks better imho.